# Windows: Set command on keyboard power button

Tags: windows, windows-8, button-remapping, zenbook

I'd like to set command on the laptop power button on a keyboard.
Is there any way to do this?
As an example I'd like to rebind it to Insert.

[image: Zenbook UX303LN Power Button to remap]

P.S. I have Windows 8.

Comment: I have it but it doesn't work for me. It says #Persistent key doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't think you can. The best option is to create a new command which does the things you want it to do using AutoHotKey or global commands to execute a bat file or similar.

Comment: I have AutoHotKey. :)

Comment: Shutdown button is not the power button on a keyboard?

Comment: Ah, got you. But I don't need to get new approach to shutdown my PC. I need to set new key behavior.

Comment: No, no. http://www.ultrabookreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/keyboard.jpg
Can you see the power in the right top corner? :)
So, I'd like to make it like delete or insert.

Comment: I can't, it's blocked at work, but, I can understand you mean it is a button your keyboard. The problem is, I don't think you can overwrite this. So instead, don't press it. Create a different way of closing the PC which first does what ever you want it to do, and then shutdown the PC

Comment: Yeah, it's the one way that I've found so far. :) I've added an image of the keyboard to the description.

Comment: But you know developers made it more secure. When I press SHIFT+PowerButton it works like delete. So, this could be done then I can replace simple pressing.